# Occultations of Triton

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, occultation, triton, sofia

I've been listening to an episode of the ["NASA in Silicon Valley" podcast about the SOFIA mission](https://www.nasa.gov/ames/nisv-podcast-Kimberly-Ennico-Smith-Michael-Person).

One of the techniques they use at SOFIA is stellar occultations to study different objects.

My impression was that the *occultations by Pluto happen much more often than by Triton*. Is this true and why is that?

Comment: I only skimmed the link, but do you mean occultations *by* Pluto and Triton?

Comment: @barrycarter independently - a probability of *Pluto in front of a distant star* vs *Triton in front of distant star* events..hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: OK, those would be occultations *by* Pluto/Triton, not *of*. Edited question to fix.

Comment: @barrycarter apologies, still getting the basics. Thanks, good to know! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pluto is actually smaller in diameter than Triton, and is also farther away, meaning that Triton covers roughly 1.4x (according to WA) the angle that Pluto does, making occultation that much more probable apriori, ignoring their actual orbits.

In addition to the above, New Horizons recently observed Pluto's atmosphere with far more detail than what we can do from here on Earth, so it makes sense to measure a different target.